# DataFrame.equals() returns False when comparing data frames with the same content but initialized differently

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The following code is supposedly creating two identical data frames, but the test for equality returns False:

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": []})
print(df1)
print(df2)
print(df1.equals(df2))
```

Here is the output produced by the code above:

```
Command Line Arguments
   
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [A]
Index: []
False
```

Why does `df1.equals(df2)` return False?

Comment: df1 and df2 have different data types: object vs float

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a method for testing equality with more detail:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas.testing import assert_frame_equal

df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=["A"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A": []})

assert_frame_equal(df1,df2)
```

Output

```
DataFrame.index classes are not equivalent
[left]:  Index([], dtype='object')
[right]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=0, step=1)
```

Then

```
assert_frame_equal(df1.reset_index(drop=True),df2.reset_index(drop=True))
```

Output

```
Attribute "dtype" are different
[left]:  object
[right]: float64
```

Finally, this will get you there

```
df1.reset_index(drop=True).equals(df2.astype(object).reset_index(drop=True))
```

Comment: Chris, thank you for the detailed answer! Actually, I will use assert_frame_equal(left, right, check_dtype=False, check_index_type=False) since the failure was observed in the unit test.